# Print a list as Matrix

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I want to do something like this but in c# :

```
for element in [self.squares[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(self.squares), 3)]: // this is in python.
```

as a result in the output would be like this:

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,0]
[0,0,0]
```

how can I do that but in C#? I know that is better with a matrix, but I want to represent a  Tic Tac Toe board and I think that is better do it in the python way, because i want to find adjacency to implement the Min-Max algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a simple way

```
public static void Print(int[][] matrix)
{
    foreach (var row in matrix)
        Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(",", row)}]");
}
```

and another version if you have a list which it's length is 9 (tic tac toe data maybe)

```
public static void PrintMatrix(List<int> tictactoe)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 3)
        Console.WriteLine($"[{tictactoe[i]},{tictactoe[i + 1]},{tictactoe[i + 2]}]");
}
```

Comment: Oh my god what they did with C# -- you pass actual code as a string.

Comment: @Joker It's called [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Comment: Just to be clear, `"I am {name}"` is no problem and trivial. The problem is that you call method in that string and it looks ugly for me, it's interesting to see other solution.

Comment: i think that I missed something.  I have a 'list<int> ' and  i want  to do the same as if  the code were in python.

Comment: Are you downvoting every answer to see others' solution? :D @Joker

Comment: because that's the way you write code not the way I do and it does not make any improvement(code readability and performance).  @Joker

Comment: Exactly readability - you deliberately wrote classic solution in bad way.

Comment: Feel free to do what you like @Joker, you are not making the community a better place.

Comment: Funny it's not me writing bad code and then, after cleanup suggested, removing it with such explanation.

Comment: If you can do better then add an answer and let the community decide. @Joker

Comment: Only care about OP not a community. This time OP has changed the subject of question from "matrix" to "list of ints" and actually there is no more reason to discuss this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make some of the functions similar to python's look. Still some more stuff can be done to make it look more similar, but from what I can see so far that would involve some [lambda functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) which may be a little over kill here. Can test run [here](http://rextester.com/) if need be.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> matrix = MakeList(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
            foreach(var element in Matrixify(3, matrix))
                Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(element));
        }

        // Used to make list easier...
        public static List<int> MakeList(params int[] elements)
        {
            return new List<int>(elements);
        }

        // Used for testing display.
        public static string ArrayToString(int[] arr)
        {
            return "[" + string.Join(",", arr) + "]";   
        }

        // Breaks a list into a matrix where delta is the # columns and # rows = len(list) / delta.
        public static int[][] Matrixify(int delta, List<int> list)
        {
            // Get a range of start index points.
            int[] arr = range(0, len(list), delta);
            // Used to make the matrix.
            List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>();
            // Chops up into rows.
            foreach(var i in arr)
                 result.Add(getRow(i, i + delta, list));
            // Sends back as an array of arrays (aka matrix).
            return result.ToArray();
        }

        // Grabs a row of the list passed in.
        public static int[] getRow(int start, int stop, List<int> list)
        {
            return list.GetRange(start, stop - start).ToArray();
        }

        // Works similar to python's len function.
        public static int len(List<int> list)
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
        public static int len(int[] list)
        {
            return list.Length;
        }

        // Works similar to python's range function.
        public static int[] range(int start, int stop, int step) 
        {
            int size = stop / step;
            int[] arr = new int[size];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                arr[i] = start + (i * step);
            return arr;
        }
        public static int[] range(int start, int stop)
        {
            return range(start, stop, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now, I think you might not get the result you want because in *C#* primitive datatypes are not passed by reference. So, a way around that would be to change `int` to a class. Here is something that might work for you:

```
    public class INT
    {
        private int _i;
        public INT()      { _i = 0; }
        public INT(int i) { _i = i; }
        // Used to access the _i member.
        public int self
        {
            get {return _i;}
            set {_i = value;}
        }
        // Used to display what is stored inside.
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _i + "";
        }
    }
```

Then can have the modified version in order to make it to where you can change the values in your matrix.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class INT
        {
            private int _i;
            public INT()      { _i = 0; }
            public INT(int i) { _i = i; }
            // Used to access the _i member.
            public int self
            {
                get {return _i;}
                set {_i = value;}
            }
            // Used to display what is stored inside.
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return _i + "";
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<INT> matrix = MakeList(9);
            foreach(var element in Matrixify(3, matrix))
                Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(element));
        }

        // Used to make list easier...
        public static List<INT> MakeList(int count)
        {
            List<INT> list = new List<INT>();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                list.Add(new INT());
            return list;
        }

        // Used for testing display.
        public static string ArrayToString(INT[] arr)
        {
            return "[" + string.Join<INT>(",", arr) + "]";
        }

        // Breaks a list into a matrix where delta is the # columns and # rows = len(list) / delta.
        public static INT[][] Matrixify(int delta, List<INT> list)
        {
            // Get a range of start index points.
            int[] arr = range(0, len(list), delta);
            // Used to make the matrix.
            List<INT[]> result = new List<INT[]>();
            // Chops up into rows.
            foreach(var i in arr)
                 result.Add(getRow(i, i + delta, list));
            // Sends back as an array of arrays (aka matrix).
            return result.ToArray();
        }

        // Grabs a row of the list passed in.
        public static INT[] getRow(int start, int stop, List<INT> list)
        {
            return list.GetRange(start, stop - start).ToArray();
        }

        // Works similar to python's len function.
        public static int len(List<INT> list)
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
        public static int len(List<int> list)
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
        public static int len(int[] list)
        {
            return list.Length;
        }

        // Works similar to python's range function.
        public static int[] range(int start, int stop, int step) 
        {
            int size = stop / step;
            int[] arr = new int[size];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                arr[i] = start + (i * step);
            return arr;
        }
        public static int[] range(int start, int stop)
        {
            return range(start, stop, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to some degree.

Comment: @SalvadorMacias No problem. Have you been able to implement something that answers your question? Or, are you looking for something closer to _python_? Just wondering, because if you need something more specific I can see what I can do. On a side note, it seems as though you have a good understanding of _python_. Why are you moving to _C#_?